# Can we start using "Go to" keyboard shortcuts in Teams?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams, keyboard-shortcuts

I find this slightly frustrating - in a Team, if I click <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to visit the Questions page, it heads right over to the main Stack Overflow questions' page instead.  Can we start using these shortcuts within Teams?